# UWP MapControl.MapServiceToken from Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-xaml

Does anyone know how get the MapServiceToken for the MapControl from Microsoft Azure?

My system admin had set up the Bing Maps API for Enterprise in Azure portal however when I try to use either the MASTERKEY or QUERYKEY, I am still getting "Warning: MapServiceToken not specified".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how get the MapServiceToken for the MapControl from Microsoft Azure?

The `MapServiceToken` for the `MapControl` is not got from Azure. This key is a [basic key or enterprise key](https://www.microsoft.com/maps/create-a-bing-maps-key.aspx) created from [Bing Maps Developer Center](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Announcement?redirect=True).    For how to create a key for [MapControl.MapServiceToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn637036) please reference [Request a maps authentication key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/authentication-key).

> when I try to use either the MASTERKEY or QUERYKEY, I am still getting "Warning: MapServiceToken not specified".

The `MASTERKEY` and `QUERYKEY` are not for `MapServiceToken`, they are for [Geocoding and Managing Data Sources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh698204.aspx). It requires the `MASKTERKEY` or `QUERTKEY` when you request [Data Source Management API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585132.aspx). These two keys provided by azure `Bing Maps API for Enterprise` are for you visiting the Bing data sources which are created by azure service(E.g. a blob service location may be a Bing data source for visiting). You can also create your Bing data source with  `MASKTERKEY` and `QUERTKEY` under Bing Maps developer center.

[image]